# What can be accessed when the stack pointer is displaced in a function assembly?

Tags: pointers, assembly

Below is portion of assembly code and I'm curious as to what the stack pointer on the last line is accessing? If I recall correctly, when the base pointer is displaced with a positive value, it accesses parameters that are passed, and, negative values, possible local variables. From what I'm assuming, going up the stack from the stack pointer, would access a local variable within the same function?

```
main:
0x0804848a <+0>:  push  %ebp
0x0804848b <+1>:  mov   %esp,%ebp
0x0804848d <+3>:  and   $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x08048490 <+6>:  sub   $0x20,%esp
0x08048493 <+9>:  movl   $0xa,0x1c(%esp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's accessing a local variable. In 32 bit code you should never access negative offset from the stack pointer, so you can't tell the difference between locals and arguments from that. You can however tell that the preceding `sub $0x20, %esp` just reserved space for 32 bytes of locals and `0x1c` falls into this range, thus it is a local.